# Solr replication is creating a lot of indexes

Tags: solr, replication

Im having a problem with solr Replication.

I can't put images to show you, but in the server, the are a lot of folder with name: index.20120909073102, index.20120909081811, index.20120909081711, index.20120909080711, index.20120909065611...

When the Slave get the info from Master, it creates a new index with the date. But I want to replicate just to one folder. Is there a way to configure it?

Tnks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be an issue effecting Solr versions prior to 4.0-BETA. Please see JIRA issue [SOLR-1781](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1781) for more details

Comment: Yes is an issue. We are changing to 4.0-BETA soon. Tnks!